# How do I list all of the items in a dictionary by biggest value to lowest value using Python and Django?

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary

So I have this as my html file.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Problem: <input type="text" name="poi" autofocus>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <hr>
</form>
<br>
<ul>
    {% for u in sort %}
        <li>{{ u|safe }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
<ul>
```

and I have my variable called sort which takes all of the items in a dictionary `dictionary = {'hi': 5, 'hey': 3, 'hiya': 1}` and sort them by highest to lowest value using the following.

```
for w in sorted(dictionary, key=dictionary.get, reverse=True):
    sort.append(w)
```

Now the list is in order from highest to lowest values. As you can see in the html file, I am trying to print them all in order. What's going wrong is that it's not printing anything. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: See the following for `render`.

```
try:
    return HttpResponse(request, 'patrec.html', {'sort':sort})
except:
    return render(request, 'patrec.html')
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that `sort` contains what you expect?  (Have you printed its contents in a logging message in your view code?)  Are you passing `sort` into the template `render` call?

Comment: I made an edit. Check it out when you get the chance

Comment: Is data fetch from db? If yes then you can use django ORM. Check out this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `HttpResponse` in a wrong way. It is destined to throw an exception because that's not how it works. Hence it raises an exception all the time and within `except` block it will return result of `render` where you are not passing the `{'sort': sort}` as context. So just remove the `try` and `except` block along with `HttpResponse`. You should only have this:

```
return render(request, 'patrec.html', {'sort': sort})
```

Comment: I kept the `try...except` and it works fine. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with

```
import heapq
list1=heapq.nlargest(len(dict1), dict1, key=dict1.get)
print(list1)
```

Where, `dict1` is the dictionary name.

As heapq comes built in with Python 3, you don't need to pip install anything.